# how to store LinkedHashMap value into double type array

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I want to store `LinkedHashMap` value into `double` type `array`. How to do that ?

I tried in this way

```
 Double[] avg=  (Double[]) averageMap.values().toArray();
```

where `averageMap` is:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Double> averageMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();
```

but I have the following exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Double;
```

Comment: Okay, what is the problem and  question ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ when i do as mentioned above then following error comes:-java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Double;

Comment: Did you try the existing answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will work for you but its not good enough

```
        Object[] objArray = averageMap.values().toArray();
        double[] dblArray = new double[objArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
            dblArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(objArray[i].toString());
        }
```

`averageMap.values().toArray();` method returns object[] so you have to cast it to Double or pars it to double[]

but its **not good practice** to parse it to double.instead of double use Double class.it is wrapper class so autoboxing 
done automatically so no need to worry

Comment: I have to finally store the value of LinkedHaspMap into double type of array i.e primitive type as this value will be used further into ChartDirector.XYChart method which takes primitive type arguments.

Comment: than try this one its work for you

Answer (score 1):

The `toArray` function might be a bit complicated. It returns an `Object[]` which cannot be cast to `Double[]`. You have to use this code snippet instead:

```
Collection<Double> values = averageMap.values();
Double[] avg = values.toArray(new Double[values.size()]);
```